# What is the concept of "weak conformance" in Scala?

Tags: scala, scala-2.8

I just recently encountered the term "Weak Conformance" (in Stack Overflow user [retronym](https://stackoverflow.com/users/160378/retronym)'s answer to *[How to set up implicit conversion to allow arithmetic between numeric types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088979/how-to-set-up-implicit-conversion-to-allow-arithmetic-between-numeric-types)*).

What is it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> 3.5.3 Weak Conformance In some situations Scala uses a more general
>   conformance relation. A type S weakly
>   conforms to a type T , written S <:<sub>w</sub> T
>   , if S <: T or both S and T are
>   primitive number types and S precedes
>   T in the following ordering.

- Byte <:<sub>w</sub> Short
- Byte <:<sub>w</sub> Character
- Short <:<sub>w</sub> Int
- Int <:<sub>w</sub> Long
- Long <:<sub>w</sub> Float
- Float <:<sub>w</sub> Double

> A weak least upper bound is a
>   least upper bound with respect to weak
>   conformance.

Where is this used? For one thing, it determines the type of `if` expressions:

> The type of the conditional expression
>   is the weak least upper bound (§3.5.3) of the types of e2 and e3

In Scala 2.7.x, this would by of type `AnyVal`, the least uppper bound of `Int` and `Double`. In 2.8.x, it types as `Double`.

```
scala> if (true) 1 else 1d
res0: Double = 1.0
```

Similarly:

```
scala> try { 1 } catch { case _ => 1.0 }
res2: Double = 1.0

scala> (new {}: Any) match { case 1 => 1; case _ => 1.0 }
res6: Double = 1.0

scala> def pf[R](pf: PartialFunction[Any, R]): PartialFunction[Any, R] = pf
pf: [R](pf: PartialFunction[Any,R])PartialFunction[Any,R]

scala> pf { case 1 => 1; case _ => 1d }
res4: PartialFunction[Any,Double] = <function1>
```

Another place it is used is in type inference:

```
scala> def foo[A](a1: A, a2: A): A = a1
foo: [A](a1: A,a2: A)A

scala> foo(1, 1d)
res8: Double = 1.0

scala> def foos[A](as: A*): A = as.head
foos: [A](as: A*)A

scala> foos(1, 1d)
res9: Double = 1.0
```

And also for simple numeric widening:

> Numeric Widening. If e has a primitive
>   number type which weakly conforms
>   (§3.5.3) to the expected type, it is
>   widened to the expected type using one
>   of the
>   6.26 Implicit Conversions 97 numeric conversion methods toShort, toChar,
>   toInt, toLong, toFloat, toDouble
>   defined in §12.2.1. expected type is a
>   primitive numeric type Byte, Short or
>   Char, and the expression e is an
>   integer literal fitting in the range
>   of that type, it is converted to the
>   same literal in that type.

```
scala> 1: Double
res10: Double = 1.0
```

**UPDATE**

As pointed out by Daniel, the spec is wrong about which types have weak conformance. Let's ask the compiler itself:

```
scala> :power
** Power User mode enabled - BEEP BOOP      **
** scala.tools.nsc._ has been imported      **
** New vals! Try repl, global, power        **
** New cmds! :help to discover them         **
** New defs! Type power.<tab> to reveal     **

scala> settings.maxPrintString = 10000


scala> import global.definitions._
import global.definitions._

scala> (for{c1 <- ScalaValueClasses;
      c2 <- ScalaValueClasses
      isNSC = isNumericSubClass(c1, c2)
      if isNSC
  } yield ("isNumericSubClass (%s, %s) = %b" format (c1, c2, isNSC))).mkString("\n")


res5: String =
isNumericSubClass (class Byte, class Byte) = true
isNumericSubClass (class Byte, class Short) = true
isNumericSubClass (class Byte, class Int) = true
isNumericSubClass (class Byte, class Long) = true
isNumericSubClass (class Byte, class Float) = true
isNumericSubClass (class Byte, class Double) = true
isNumericSubClass (class Short, class Short) = true
isNumericSubClass (class Short, class Int) = true
isNumericSubClass (class Short, class Long) = true
isNumericSubClass (class Short, class Float) = true
isNumericSubClass (class Short, class Double) = true
isNumericSubClass (class Int, class Int) = true
isNumericSubClass (class Int, class Long) = true
isNumericSubClass (class Int, class Float) = true
isNumericSubClass (class Int, class Double) = true
isNumericSubClass (class Long, class Long) = true
isNumericSubClass (class Long, class Float) = true
isNumericSubClass (class Long, class Double) = true
isNumericSubClass (class Char, class Int) = true
isNumericSubClass (class Char, class Long) = true
isNumericSubClass (class Char, class Char) = true
isNumericSubClass (class Char, class Float) = true
isNumericSubClass (class Char, class Double) = true
isNumericSubClass (class Float, class Float) = true
isNumericSubClass (class Float, class Double) = true
isNumericSubClass (class Double, class Double) = true
```

Answer (score 5):

To complete [Sandor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094380/what-is-the-concept-of-weak-conformance-in-scala/3094785#3094785), that new feature in 2.8 is still being baked (and fixed).

In [this thread](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Weak-Conformance-tt2231341.html#a2231341), Esser uncovers a nasty side-effect:

```
scala> val a= 10 
a: Int = 10 

scala> val b= 3 
b: Int = 3 

scala> if (b!=0) a/b else Double.NaN 
res0: Double = 3.0 

scala> def div1(a: Int, b: Int) = if (b!=0) a/b else Double.NaN 
div1: (a: Int,b: Int)Double 

scala> def div2(a: Int, b: Int): Double = if (b!=0) a/b else Double.NaN 
div2: (a: Int,b: Int)Double 

scala> div1(10,3) 
res1: Double = 3.0 

scala> div2(10,3) 
res2: Double = 3.3333333333333335
```

> Seems interesting, because the implicitly found result type is `Double` and the result is 3.0.
>   If Double is explicitly given, the result is 3.33...

In [this thread](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.scala/20441), Martin Odersky adds (June 21st):

> you have uncovered a serious unintended side-effect of the weak conformance rules in overloading resolution.
>   **The problem was that arguments of overloaded methods are required to conform weakly, whereas the result type was required to conform strongly.**
>
> This favored the `Float => Float` addition method on an `Int` over the `Int => Int` method if the result type was Float.
>   I was trying to be conservative in my change to weak conformance in that I required weak  conformance only where it looked absolutely necessary.
>   But it seems now that being conservative caused the problem we are looking at!

And yet another Scala RC release ;)

---

Confirmed in [this thread by Martin Odersky (June 22d)](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Status-of-2-8-td2263878.html#a2263878):

> So there will be a RC7 with so far three changes from RC6:
>
> 1. `val x: Double = 10/3` will give `3.0`, not `3.3333333` - that was the regression I was mentioning
> 2. [...]
> 3. [...]
>
> That's it. Our priorities now are to roll out 2.8 as quickly as we can, and at the same time avoid really bad regressions such as (1) above.
>
> Timeline:
>
> - We will wait one more week to get feedback on RC6.
> - We will push out RC7 early next week.
>     If no further problems show up RC7 would then turn into 2.8 final 10-14 days after it is released.

(so around July 12th, I believe, but this guess is mine alone ;) )

Answer (score 4):

According to Scala lang spec 2.8:
http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/pdfs/ScalaReference.pdf

3.5.3 Weak Conformance
In some situations Scala uses a more genral conformance relation. A type S weakly
conforms to a type T , written S <:w T , if S <: T or both S and T are primitive number
types and S precedes T in the following ordering.
Byte <:w Short
Byte <:w Character
Short <:w Int
Int <:w Long
Long <:w Float
Float <:w Double
A weak least upper bound is a least upper bound with respect to weak conformance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `Char` conforms to `Int` as well.