# Misleading compile time error

Tags: scala, compiler-errors

Why does the following compile?

```
scala> val ch1 = 'a' + 'b'
ch1: Int = 195
```

but the following doesn't?

```
scala> var ch1 = 'a'
ch1: Char = a

scala> ch1 += 'b'
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: Char
       ch1 += 'b'
           ^

scala> ch1 = ch1 + 'b'
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: Char
       ch1 = ch1 + 'b'
                 ^
```

And why is the error message so misleading? Why does it say `required: Char` when what I am passing is clearly a `Char`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you add a `Char` and another `Char`, the result is an `Int`.

```
scala> 'a' + 'c'      
res2: Int = 196
```

That's the "found" part of the error message.

Answer (score 3):

This might help:

[What is the concept of "weak conformance" in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094380/what-is-the-concept-of-weak-conformance-in-scala)

http://lmazy.verrech.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/scala_type_hierarchy.png

Regards,
raichoo

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have to help the compiler here if you annotate the ch1 as Int it works as expected?
The problem is I guess your intend is misread by the compiler :)
How should it know that you declare a Char to get it's int value to add another Int out if it? You are trying to change the type of a variable after assignment , how could , should that work? So start with var ch1:Int='a' and it works.