# implicit conversion over multiple levels, why does int to double automatically work?

Tags: scala

I was always figuring implicit conversions over multiple levels is not possible in scala (unless you define view bounds: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-and-view-bounds.html)

But it seems that there is a flaw in the type system or an inconsistency. 
Following an example (adapted from [How can I chain implicits in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332801/how-can-i-chain-implicits-in-scala))

```
class A(val n: Double){
  def total = n + 10
}

object T1{
  implicit def toA(n: Double): A = new A(n)
  val i : Int = 5
  println(i.total) //Why does this work?
  println(5.2.total)
}
```

I do not really understand why the implicit conversion from Int -> Double -> A works. Can someone please explain the reasons? Thanks

Comment: widening conversions are different from implicit conversions: https://developmentality.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/scala-type-inferencing-gotchas/

Comment: In the language reference weak conformance might help understanding (these are not implicit conversions): http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#weak-conformance and this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3094380

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It happens via a different mechanism, unique to the numeric types, called *numeric widening*.

[SLS 6.26.1 Value Conversions](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#value-conversions) says:

> The following five implicit conversions can be applied to an expression *e* which has some value type *T* and which is type-checked with some expected type *pt*.
>
> Static Overloading Resolution
>
> Type Instantiation
>
> Numeric Widening
>
> Numeric Literal Narrowing
>
> Value Discarding
>
> View Application
>
> Dynamic Member Selection

(Okay, that's more than five....not sure why :)

The one of interest is numeric widening:

> If *e* has a primitive number type which [weakly conforms](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#weak-conformance) to the expected type, it is widened to the expected type using one of the numeric conversion methods `toShort`, `toChar`, `toInt`, `toLong`, `toFloat`, `toDouble` defined [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/12-the-scala-standard-library.html#numeric-value-types).

[3.5.16 Weak Conformance](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#weak-conformance) says

> In some situations Scala uses a more general conformance relation. A type S weakly conforms to a type T, written S<:wT, if S<:T or both S and T are primitive number types and S precedes T in the following ordering.
>
> ```
> Byte  <:w Short
> Short <:w Int
> Char  <:w Int
> Int   <:w Long
> Long  <:w Float
> Float <:w Double
> ```

So `println(i.total)` becomes `println(i.total.toFloat)` because `Int <:w <: Long <: Float`.

Java (and C# and many other languages) have numeric widening, and Scala decided to keep it.

Note that the reverse does not work: a `Float` cannot be implicitly converted to `Int` via this way, since magnitude could be lost; it's not a "widening".

You can add `-Ywarn-numeric-widen` and get a warning when this happens.

Comment: at least now it is already corrected: `The following seven implicit conversions can` (...)

Answer (score 1):

As Gabor already commented, this is [due to numeric widening](https://developmentality.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/scala-type-inferencing-gotchas/). If you run with the `-print` option, you will see that a `.toDouble` is appended to the `i`, which then allows it to use the `toA` `implicit`. You can run `scalac` with the `warn-numeric-widen` and this will at least give you the following:

```
<console>:14: warning: implicit numeric widening
     println(i.total) //Why does this work?
             ^
```