# Implicit conversion from Int to Double in scala doesn't work

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, scalac

I have written some implicit code as shown below, and I am wondering why the `i2d` function implicit conversation isn't invoked.

```
object Test {
  implicit def i2d(x: Int): Double = {
    println("foo")
    x.toDouble
  }

  implicit def d2i(x: Double): Int = {
    x.toInt
  }

  val x: Int = 10
  val y: Double = x
  val z: Int = 3.5
}
```

The **output** of `scalac -Xprint:typer Test.scala`

```
// Test.scala
[[syntax trees at end of typer]] 
package <empty> {
  object Test extends scala.AnyRef {
    def <init>(): Test.type = {
      Test.super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    implicit def i2d(x: Int): Double = {
      scala.this.Predef.println("foo");
      x.toDouble
    };
    implicit def d2i(x: Double): Int = x.toInt;
    private[this] val x: Int = 10;
    <stable> <accessor> def x: Int = Test.this.x;
    private[this] val y: Double = Test.this.x.toDouble;
    <stable> <accessor> def y: Double = Test.this.y;
    private[this] val z: Int = Test.this.d2i(3.5);
    <stable> <accessor> def z: Int = Test.this.z
  }
}
```

**Specs**

- scalac version is 2.11.8.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28252060/implicit-conversion-over-multiple-levels-why-does-int-to-double-automatically-w

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This was a lot more involved than I thought.

At first, I thought it was because of how Scala resolves implicits. Somehow, I thought [this implicit in `Int.scala`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.8/src/library/scala/Int.scala#L474) was getting prioritized. The rules for priority are usually intuitive, but for edge cases like this, we refer to [6.26.3 Overloading Resolution](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#overloading-resolution). The thing that confused me though was that the call to `int2double` isn't there - it is already inlined to `.toDouble`!!

Having dug a bit more, it appears that there is an edge case concerning value types which applies to the conversion from `Int` to `Double`. Something called [weak conformance](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#weak-conformance) dictates how we convert `Byte -> Short -> Int -> Long -> Float -> Double`. So, all in all, I don't think you can overrule this builtin conversion...

This conversion is known as [numeric widening](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#value-conversions)

> #### Numeric Widening
>
> If `e` has a primitive number type which weakly conforms to the expected type, it is widened to the expected type
>   using one of the numeric conversion methods `toShort`, `toChar`,
>   `toInt`, `toLong`, `toFloat`, `toDouble`...

## EDIT

Also, in case anyone is wondering *why* this is a thing, from [Martin Odersky](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-internals/Gi-54GeWv-M%5B1-25%5D) (this is an old link - don't trust what is being said here in general), we run into common problems if we don't have these extra special conversions:

> ```
> scala-hypothetical> val x = List(1, 2.0) 
> x: List[AnyVal]
> ```
>
> Not very intuitive...

Answer (score 3):

<strike>Look at the last line in the Int companion object. I think it has to do with that and the concept of views:</strike>

```
object Int extends AnyValCompanion {
  /** The smallest value representable as a Int.
   */
  final val MinValue = java.lang.Integer.MIN_VALUE

  /** The largest value representable as a Int.
   */
  final val MaxValue = java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE

  /** Transform a value type into a boxed reference type.
   *
   *  @param  x   the Int to be boxed
   *  @return     a java.lang.Integer offering `x` as its underlying value.
   */
  def box(x: Int): java.lang.Integer = java.lang.Integer.valueOf(x)

  /** Transform a boxed type into a value type.  Note that this
   *  method is not typesafe: it accepts any Object, but will throw
   *  an exception if the argument is not a java.lang.Integer.
   *
   *  @param  x   the java.lang.Integer to be unboxed.
   *  @throws     ClassCastException  if the argument is not a java.lang.Integer
   *  @return     the Int resulting from calling intValue() on `x`
   */
  def unbox(x: java.lang.Object): Int = x.asInstanceOf[java.lang.Integer].intValue()

  /** The String representation of the scala.Int companion object.
   */
  override def toString = "object scala.Int"

  /** Language mandated coercions from Int to "wider" types.
   */
  implicit def int2long(x: Int): Long = x.toLong
  implicit def int2float(x: Int): Float = x.toFloat
  implicit def int2double(x: Int): Double = x.toDouble
}
```

[image]

See also: [Where does Scala look for implicits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits)

**EDIT**

as per @som-snytt's comment:

```
scala -Ywarn-numeric-widen
Welcome to Scala 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_91).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> object Test {
     |   implicit def i2d(x: Int): Double = {
     |     println("foo")
     |     x.toDouble
     |   }
     |
     |   implicit def d2i(x: Double): Int = {
     |     x.toInt
     |   }
     |
     |   val x: Int = 10
     |   val y: Double = x
     |   val z: Int = 3.5
     | }
<console>:22: warning: implicit numeric widening
         val y: Double = x
                         ^
```

Also, to add to @Alec's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38967057/101715) about widening: http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#value-conversions

from: http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#weak-conformance

> Weak Conformance
>   In some situations Scala uses a more general conformance relation. A type >SS weakly conforms to a type TT, written S<:wTS<:wT, if S<:TS<:T or both >SS and TT are primitive number types and SS precedes TT in the following >ordering.
>
> Byte  <:w<:w Short
>
> Short <:w<:w Int
>
> Char  <:w<:w Int
>
> Int   <:w<:w Long
>
> Long  <:w<:w Float
>
> Float <:w<:w Double
>
> A weak least upper bound is a least upper bound with respect to weak conformance.

Comment: Use `-Ywarn-numeric-widen` to make the conversions visible.

Comment: Misleadingly, the implicit has, in this case, nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: @Yaneeve Alecs answer explains it well.

Comment: @Alec the ML thread you quote includes example of the companion implicit methods used as fallback mechanism in 2.10, and for views in 2.11.

Comment: @som-snytt I don't think that comment was meant for me. :)

Comment: @Alec for both of you, to clarify the status of the methods vis-a-vis numeric widening. Another footnote is that spec says the conversions are defined in Predef, which is not (now) true.

Comment: @som-snytt, thanks so much for your input. Now, though, I am somewhat lost. I don't know what "_ML_ thread" is, and I can't even guess (sorry for the ignorance). Also, please, elaborate on what it means "example of the companion implicit methods used as **fallback mechanism** in 2.10, and for **views** in 2.11."

Comment: @Yaneeve pardon, the other answer has "old link" for a Mailing List thread, which is still classic. See the Paul Phillips message for example that uses the conversion method in 2.10 but not in 2.11; Jason Zaugg chimes in that the methods are still available in 2.11 if you want `Int => Double` etc.

Comment: Thanks for the (double) clarification :)