# How to suppress automatic conversion from Long to Double when creating an array containing type AnyVal

Tags: scala, type-conversion

I was trying to create an array containing all `Int`, `Long` and `Double` types. However, I found that the `Long` and `Int` types are automatically converted to `Double`.
Here's a minimal example,

```
object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {  
    val types = Array[Byte]('i', 'l', 'd', 'd')
    val array = Array[String]("1", "2000000", "20.0", "2020.0")
    val values = array.zip(types) map { case (s, t) => 
      t match {
        case 'i' => s.toInt
        case 'l' => s.toLong
        case 'd' => s.toDouble
      }
    }
    values.foreach { println }
  }
}
```

The result is

```
1.0
2000000.0
20.0
2020.0
```

How can I avoid such conversion? Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting any deprecation warnings? e.g., "Widening conversion from Long to Double is deprecated because it loses precision. Write `.toDouble` instead." https://scastie.scala-lang.org/04t4VlyPTPeN6EokyPjA1Q

Comment: Does this answer your question? [implicit conversion over multiple levels, why does int to double automatically work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28252060/implicit-conversion-over-multiple-levels-why-does-int-to-double-automatically-w)

Comment: To prevent this, you can explicitly declare the type of your array: `val values : Array[Number]` , will get you an array of `Number`s which is the super type of all the types in the array.

Comment: @jrook I made a Scastie snippet: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/i5nOF5BDQVKXI5I61zceMg It works. I think you should write this up as an answer...

Comment: @AlonsodelArte Yes, when I tried on scastie, I get that warnings. But I want to get long and converting to `Double` will cause precision loss

Comment: @jrook I read through the problem in your link. I think that's probably the cause of my issue

Comment: Yes. Indeed, that works! Thanks

Comment: @YanqiHuang, going with `AnyVal`, you will have to cast array elements to get the right type out of the result array (e.g. `values.head.asInstanceOf[Int]`). This could lead to `ClassCastException`. While `Number` is a java construct, using its `doulbeValue()` or `intValue()` won't throw exceptions which may or not help you in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the compiler tries to come with a least surprising type of the `match` expresion, which is a type all those types (`Int`, `Long` and `Double`) can be converted  to:

```
t match {
    case 'i' => s.toInt
    case 'l' => s.toLong
    case 'd' => s.toDouble
  }
```

You can use a type ascription or an assignment to provide your own type instead, which may be `Numeric` or `AnyVal`.

```
case (s, t) => (t match {
    case 'i' => s.toInt
    case 'l' => s.toLong
    case 'd' => s.toDouble
  }):AnyVal
```

or

```
    val result: AnyVal = t match {
      case 'i' => s.toInt
      case 'l' => s.toLong
      case 'd' => s.toDouble
    }
    result
```

Another alternative is to use the `:AnyVal` type ascription on any of the case results, which will also make the compiler to give up trying coming up with a more sensible type:

```
    t match {
      case 'i' => s.toInt:AnyVal
      case 'l' => s.toLong
      case 'd' => s.toDouble
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The expression

```
t match {
  case 'i' => s.toInt
  case 'l' => s.toLong
  case 'd' => s.toDouble
}
```

infers to `Double` because Scala 2 calculates **weak** least upper bound. One option is to use type ascription to tell the compiler explicitly the regular least upper bound, for example,

```
(t match {
  case 'i' => s.toInt
  case 'l' => s.toLong
  case 'd' => s.toDouble
}): AnyVal
```

Scala 3 [drops](http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/dropped-features/weak-conformance.html) the notion of weak conformance

> drops the general notion of weak conformance, and instead keeps one
> rule: Int literals are adapted to other numeric types if necessary.

so your example would work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the cleverest way: make a list of lists, then flatten.

```
val types = List[Byte]('i', 'l', 'd', 'd')
val array = List[String]("1", "2000000", "20.0", "2020.0")
val values = array.zip(types) map { 
  case (s, t) => t match {
    case 'i' => List(s.toInt)
    case 'l' => List(s.toLong)
    case 'd' => List(s.toDouble)
  }
}
values.flatten
```

Here's the Scastie snippet: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/tpLbvlg1TrKmQsqeZRsDTg

P.S. Arrays are provided in Scala mostly for the sake of Java interoperability. Otherwise prefer lists.