# Scala: Function returning an unknown type

Tags: scala, types, numbers

If I wanted to make an add method that adds values of two different types like:

```
add[T,S](op1: T, op2: S): ? = ...
```

The most notable example I can think of are the basic number types. If I add a Byte and an Int then it would return an Int. If two Bytes are added it could return an Int depending on if the -127 to 128 limit for the Byte is broken.

Further more if I wanted to create classes that had the same characteristics I would like it to do the same.

One possible solution is to have classes extend the same trait or class. But for the example of Scala primitive types this doesn't apply cause Int, Double, Float, Byte don't share a common ancestor besides Any.

I've also looked at the Numeric[T] trait but that doesn't seem to help when adding different primitive types.

Thanks
Kai

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a prime example for a some kind of joint-typeclass.

Start by defining a thing just like `Numeric[T]`, but for addability:

```
trait Addable[T, S] {
  type Result
  def add(x: T, y: S): Result
}
```

Now, define your `add` function:

```
def add[T,S](op1: T, op2: S)(implicit op: Addable[T, S]): op.Result =
  op.add(op1, op2)
```

All you have to do left, is to create implicit instances for `Addable`:

```
// Put them in the companion object, so the implicits are available
// without explicit import
object Addable {
  // Make any numeric addable
  implicit def numericAddable[T : Numeric]: Addable[T, T] = {
    new Addable[T, T] {
      type Result = T
      def add(x: T, y: T): T = {
        val op = implicitly[Numeric[T]]
        op.plus(x, y)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But you now can also define your own classes and define (assymetric) addition capability:

```
case class A(x: Int)
case class B(x: Int)
case class C(x: Int)

implicit object AddABC extends Addable[A,B] {
  type Result = C
  def add(x: A, y: B): C = C(x.x + y.x)
}
```

This will allow you to write:

```
add(A(1), B(2))
```

However, any of these will fail at compile time:

```
add(A(1), A(2))
add(B(1), A(2))
add(B(1), B(2))
```

Unfortunately, this does not work for weak conforming numeric types:

```
add(1, 1) // compiles
add(1.0, 1.0) // compiles
add(1, 1.0) // fails to compile
```

Judging from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088979/how-to-set-up-implicit-conversion-to-allow-arithmetic-between-numeric-types), there is not really another way to achieve that, than to define the cases manually (with some helper methods of course).

Comment: So I just spent today studying your solution and the one you linked to. Learning something new, I learned for the first time a byte + byte returns an int no matter what! But is there any reason why it doesnt depend on the value of the byte? It seems a bit inefficient, when you could potentially save space by keeping bytes within its number range.
And if I wanted to make the following in my code, I've been looking at Scalas "Either" type. In which case I would return an Either and then pattern match when adding in the wrapper class. Just wanted to know if there was any particular reason not to.

Comment: In Scala, byte + byte returns an int, mainly because that is what the JVM (and Java) does. I do not know why Java was designed that way.