# Function returning a dynamic type

Tags: scala

So here is the question I asked before:
[Scala: Function returning an unknown type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30175370/scala-function-returning-an-unknown-type)

This is very much a follow up on that.

Previously I asked a question about adding number types and returning the one with more precision. This was answered by using type classes for Weak Conformance rules and specifying the type there. For example an WeakConformance[Int, Double] specifies that a double will be returned.

However, when adding the complexity of bounds this poses problems. Let's say I wanted to make a type class for adding two Bytes together:

```
class ByteisAddable extends Addable[Byte, Byte] {
  def add(x: Byte, y: Byte): ? = {
    if(Byte.MaxValue - x < y)
      // this is an int
      x + y
    else
      // this is a byte
      (x + y).toByte
  }
}
```

The type class WeakConformance[Byte, Byte] cannot just specifies one type because it can be an Int or a Byte. That is the computation of adding the values has to take place before the type to return can be specified. For example the two bytes: 10 + 10 should return a byte of value 20. But the two bytes: 100 + 100 should return an int or it would overflow Byte.MaxValue.

Is there a better way to go about this? Or is there a way to specify a type after computation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are asking for is a kind of [Dependent Type System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type). Only few languages support such type systems and it is an active field of research.

You can return a dynamic type from a method by using subtyping:

```
def add(x: Byte, y: Byte): java.lang.Number = {
  if(Byte.MaxValue - x < y)
    new java.lang.Integer(x + y)
  else
    new java.lang.Byte(x + y)
}
```

However, I am assuming that this is not what you want. I assume you want the static return type to be decided dynamically.

And that is exactly the problem: You cannot have a static type based on runtime values of your program. So in order to guarantee that `add(Byte, Byte)` returns another `Byte` (without overflowing), you would need to encode some kind of judgment in your type system saying that the sum of the types doesn't overflow. And you need dependent types for that. A dummy example of a dependent type is `Byte[x < 30]`, meaning a `Byte` smaller than 30 (notation is completely arbitrary).

So unless you want to implement your own dependent type system in Scala (which is clearly beyond scope of a SO answer), I am sorry to tell you that you are out of luck.

Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935731/any-reason-why-scala-does-not-explicitly-support-dependent-types) to see what kind of lingo you are getting yourself into :)